# Excel - Multiple word search - Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Friends, I need your help on the below

Suppose in column A I have some company names or normal names, I need to do multiple word search in each cell, if matching Yes else No

For example - I want to search Davis and Patel

If A1 has Davis Erik, the result should be Yes
If A2 has Sardar Patel, the result should be Yes
If A3 has Davis Patel, the result should be Yes
If A4 has Pamela Caro, the result should be No

Could you please help here?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Names are known for 'trouble'. Unless you are sure that spaces are *always* the delimiter, you will run into trouble. A more diverse pallet of sample data is needed to determine how to address this issue.

Comment: ^^^^ For example, for "Davis", should it return "Yes" for "Davison"?

Comment: Or even; How do you know what are the names to be searched in `A B C`. Are these `A`, `B` and `C` or rather `A B` and `C` or even `A` and `B C`.

Comment: So "Davis and Patel" or "Davis or Patel"? different questions and different results. So, based on your example then only A3 will return Yes.

Comment: For example, for "Davis", should it return "Yes" for "Davison"? - Yes this is correct

Comment: So "Davis and Patel" or "Davis or Patel"? different questions and different results. So, based on your example then only A3 will return Yes --> It should be Davis or Patel

Comment: Or even; How do you know what are the names to be searched in A B C. Are these A, B and C or rather A B and C or even A and B C --> I have been given two names already so i want to check only those two names i.e., Davis or Patel... If any of the cell have this word, it should be Yes

Comment: You have missed the point of potential false positives it seems. If false positives are no issue then there are numerous questions here on SO you could check for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below formula worked:

```
=IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Davis",A1)),"Yes",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Patel",A1)),"Yes",TRUE,"No")
```

[image: working function]

Answer (score 0):

So, you can work with this and edit as you need:

```
=IFERROR(OR(IFERROR(FIND($B$1,A1,1),""),IFERROR(FIND($B$2,A1,1),"")),"No")
```

[image]

Edit: to hardcode the names:

```
=IFERROR(OR(IFERROR(FIND("Davis",A1,1),""),IFERROR(FIND("Patel",A1,1),"")),"No")
```

Comment: Is there a way that we can hardcode the names in the formula itself??? I know the formula to search one word - =IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Davis",A1),"FALSE"),"Yes","No") - This is working good. In the same way i want formula for both Davis and Patel.. In simple, Multiple word search

Comment: @KannanPrince well, an easy edit as shown. You should play with the functions so you can find out what you can do, like check out wildcards...

Comment: @Since you keep changing the question in your comment - it was originall just how to hardcode the names then you have changed that. I am not going through endless variations based on changing comments - work with what I have given you and try things.

Answer (score 0):

[See Image as well - search terms in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYUGR.png)

If data in column A then,

In cell B1:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH($E$1,A1,1),0)>0,"Yes","")
```

In cell C1:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH($F$1,A1,1),0)>0,"Yes","")
```

In cell D1:

```
=IF(B1<>"",B1,IF(C1<>"",C1,"No"))
```

Search terms in cells E1 and F1