# Extract country codes from email addresses

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, I am trying to return the two-letter country codes from email addresses in column C (e.g. "fr" for France), but ignoring generic TLDs such as "com", "net", etc. I do not want to use only `=RIGHT(C2,2)`, which works OK, because this would return e.g. "om" from ".com" - "om" is the country code for Oman.

I have tried using the following formula, however this returns False, because `RIGHT(C2,3)` is three characters and cannot only equal "."

```
=IF(RIGHT(C2,3)=".",RIGHT(C2,2),"")
```

Could someone please indicate if there is a way to use `If` with a specific character "." in the third position from the right?

Comment: So use the position of the “.” To control what happens. Or have a list of com, net etc and exclude with a vlookup() with if().

Comment: Many examples on here, this is one that shows the use of find() and if(): https://stackoverflow.com/a/73336177/4961700

Comment: Thanks - problem with a list of com, net etc is that the list would be VERY long - there are MANY new domains now e.g. .online, .singles, .asia, etc. etc.. But "." will always be 3rd from right for country domains, which are still only 2-letters.

Comment: So, consider using mid() with len() and then left() to check the first character returned.

Comment: mid() with len() will be dynamic, because email address lenghts vary. "." 3rd from right is constant.

Comment: As you can see, len()-2 will always bring back the last 3 - simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a quick start:

```
IF(LEFT(MID(H2,LEN(H2)-2,3),1)=".",MID(H2,LEN(H2)-2,3),"")
```

And tested:
[image]

So, you may need to improve it as I have not trapped for any errors.

A few further tests:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

BTW I can now wrap this in a lookup to retrieve the country name directly, e.g.

```
=XLOOKUP(IF(LEFT(MID(H2,LEN(H2)-2,3),1)=".",MID(H2,LEN(H2)-2,3),"") lookup_array, return_array)
```

Using list of country codes and countries taken from [Wikipedia's list of country TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain)

[image]